# How to find the particular solution to $y'' + \cos(t) y' = \cos(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the  particular solution to

$$y'' + \cos(t) y' = \cos(t)$$

I know that the homogeneous solution of this differential equation is given by

$$y_h (t) = A + Be^{- t \cos (t)}$$

with $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$. I think I can use the method of undetermined coefficients to find the particular solution, but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: You can integrate once to get $y'(t)=1+Ce^{-\sin t}$.

Comment: @Gonçalo how did you find this particular solution?

Comment: You may also be able to [reduce the order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order) using the known characteristic solution $\displaystyle\int e^{-\sin(t)}\,dt$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Btw, you can not use undetermined coefficients on this ode since it is not constant coefficients ode. For non-constant coefficient ode, you should use variation of parameters.

But there is no need for either of these here. You can take advantage that the ode is missing $y(t)$ and convert it to a first order ode and solve it that way.

$$
y^{\prime \prime}+\cos \left(t \right) y^{\prime}=\cos \left(t \right)
$$

This is second order ode with missing dependent variable $y$. Let
\begin{align*}
p(t) &= y^{\prime}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
p'(t) &= y^{\prime \prime}
\end{align*}
Hence the ode becomes
\begin{align*}
p^{\prime}\left(t \right)+\cos \left(t \right) p \left(t \right)-\cos \left(t \right) = 0
\end{align*}
Which is now solve for $p(t)$ as first order ode.
The integrating factor $\mu$ is
\begin{align*}
\mu &= {\mathrm e}^{\int \cos \left(t \right)d t}\\
    &= {\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)}
\end{align*}

The ode becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}\left( \mu p\right) &= \left(\mu \right) \left(\cos \left(t \right)\right) \\ 
\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} \left({\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} p\right) &= \left({\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)}\right) \left(\cos \left(t \right)\right)\\ 
\mathrm{d} \left({\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} p\right)  &= \left({\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} \cos \left(t \right)\right)\, \mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}
Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
{\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} p &= \int{{\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} \cos \left(t \right)\,\mathrm{d} t}\\ 
{\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} p &= {\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)} + c_1 
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides by the integrating factor $\mu={\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)}$ results in
\begin{align*}
p &= 1+c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{-\sin \left(t \right)}
\end{align*}
Since $p=y^{\prime}\left(t \right)$ then the new first order ode to solve is
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}\left(t \right) = 1+c_{2} {\mathrm e}^{-\sin \left(t \right)}
\end{align*}

$y$ is found by integration.
\begin{align*}
y &= \int{ \left({\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)}+c_{2}\right) {\mathrm e}^{-\sin \left(t \right)}\,\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}\\ 
&= \int \left({\mathrm e}^{\sin \left(t \right)}+c_{2}\right) {\mathrm e}^{-\sin \left(t \right)}d t + c_1 \\
&= \int{ 1+ c_2 e^{-\sin(t)} \,dt}  + c_1\\
&= t+c_1 + c_2 \int{e^{-\sin(t)} \,dt}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$$y'' + \text{cos}(t) y' = \text{cos}(t)$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$\dfrac {(y'-1)'}{  y'-1} =- \cos t$$
$$(\ln {(y'-1)})' = -\cos t$$
Integrate.
$$(\ln {(y'-1)}) = C_0-\sin t$$
$$y'-1 = Ce^{-\sin t}$$
$$(y-t)' = Ce^{-\sin t}$$
$$y =t+ C_1+ C\int e^{-\sin t}dt$$
$$\implies y_p=t$$
The solution of the homogeneous DE can't be expressed with elementary functions so keep the integral in your final solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a first-order linear ODE, so we can use the "integrating factor" technique.

Let $u = y'$. So $u$ satisfies
$$
u'(t) + \cos(t) u(t) = \cos(t).
$$
Multiplying through by the "integrating factor" $e^{\sin(t)}$, we find that
$$
\tag{1} e^{\sin(t)} u'(t) + e^{\sin(t)} \cos(t) u(t) = e^{\sin(t)} \cos(t).
$$
On the left, we recognize the derivative of $e^{\sin(t)} u(t)$. Taking antiderivatives of both sides of (1), we find that
$$
e^{\sin(t)} u(t) = e^{\sin(t)} + C
$$
for some $C \in \mathbb R$.
It follows that
$$
u(t) = 1 + C e^{-\sin(t)}.
$$
Finally, we have discovered that the function $y$ satisfies
$$
y'(t) = 1 + C e^{-\sin(t)}.
$$
I don't believe there is an elementary antiderivative for the function on the right when $C \neq 0$. But, when $C = 0$, we see that
$$
y'(t) = 1
$$
and so $y(t) = t$ is one particular solution of your ODE.